# Trigger issues with integration

Tags: apex, trigger, integration

I'm studying for the SF PD1 cert with some practice questions I found. But I have one question that is troubling me because none of the answers sound right.

Could someone help me to know if I'm ignoring something?

Here's the question:

***A developer created a new trigger that inserts a Task when a new Lead is created. After deploying to production, an outside integration chat reads task records is periodically reporting errors.
Which change should the developer make to ensure the integration is not affected with minimal impact to business logic?***

- A Deactivate the trigger before the integration runs.
- B Use a try-catch block after the insert statement.
- C Remove the Apex class from the integration user's profile.
- D Use the Database method with all or None set to false

**My understanding is the following:**

- A It wouldn't make sense o deacivate the trigger as it's a needed
  automation and it'd be impractical to disable and enable it every
  time the automation runs.
- B This kind of makes sense, but it I don't see what could be done to
  avoid errors on the integration other than not creating the task,
  which would defeat the purpose of the trigger automation.
- C I don't see the point on this one, since it's really the task
  record what should be firing the integration that reads the tasks and
  the integration user not having access to the apex class wouldn't
  make any difference.
- D This one would help either, since the error is on the integration
  and doesn;t have anything to do with insetion errors.

I know the question is a little vague and doesn't give details on what type of error they're exactly getting, but I guess there should be a valid answer with the given information.

Any help will be greatly appreaciated!

Comment: This question makes no sense. If you've just found it online somewhere, I'd say ignore it.

Comment: I really encourage using the official exam guide on Trailhead, plus associated documentation, to study for this exam. This kind of "study material" you'll find online is of _wildly_ varying quality, as you see here. We generally don't allow posts on SFSE that include anything that looks like an exam question.

Comment: I see, thanks for your suggestion. I actually resorted to this kind of resource because I already studied most of the trailhead for PD1 certification, will keep this in mind next time, thanks!!

Comment: You're right that I can find questions that make no sense like this one, but to be honest I feel this kind of content actually had helped me because I'm forced to analyze and investigate every single question, validating it with SF docs or even practical testing in a SF org :)